# Visual Basics: How to do a Find and Replace either on the selected text or the whole document?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, replace

So far I have been able to do code a find and replace for the whole text.

```
Private Sub btnFFindNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFFindNext.Click

    Dim search As String
    Dim length As String

    search = textToFind.Text 
    length = textToFind.Text.Length

        lastposition = RichTextBox.Find(textToFind.Text, lastposition, RichTextBoxFinds.None)

    RichTextBox.SelectionStart = lastposition
    RichTextBox.SelectionLength = length
    lastposition = lastposition + 1
```

However, I now need to make it possible so that if the user selects some text, then the Find and Replace is only performed on that selection.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use <[ricthTextBox.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab8wkhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)> with arguments for start and end(Similar to what you have use).
You can take the first start point and the end from richTextBox's events (SelectionChanged)

Tell me how is going.